# Subquery returned more than 1 value on JOIN query

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I want split a row from `vusers` that contain data like below

```
vusers     branchuserid
name       12,13,10
putra      10,11,9
eko        5
gilang     7,8
```

tbl_branch

```
   ID     branch
----------------------
    5     new york
    6     bandung
    7     jakarta
    8     sulawesi
    9     makasar
    10    jalan
    11    menuju
    12    kebenaran
    13    sulit
```

I want to get branch from `tbl_branch` where ID contain `branchuserid`.

I have a problem with my query. I want to get value for JOIN statement, but it doesn't  work for me. here is my query

```
 SELECT vUsers.userID, tbl_branch.branch  FROM vUsers JOIN tbl_branch
     ON (SELECT Split.Data.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS BranchID FROM
     (Select CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(userAccessbranch,',', '</M><M>')+ '</M>'
     AS XML) AS String FROM vUsers) AS Data CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M')
     AS Split(Data)) = tbl_branch.ID
```

Comment: You can improve this question. Give us some sample data, the results you want, and the results you actually get.

Chances are, you will come up with the answer while assembling the information.

Comment: Subqueries can and often do return more than one result.  Maybe start with why you believe it shouldn't.  You are using no distincts and no where clauses so I would be expecting multiple results as well unless the table only has one record.

Comment: You have two subqueries. Run each of them independently, and see which one returns more than one row.

Comment: Consider changing your schema and using a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) instead of storing arrays. That won't immediately solve the problem at hand but it will at least make for more efficient queries in the future, including those you may need to solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you are get just one record from your subqueries, you can return only one by using `TOP 1`

```
SELECT vUsers.userID, tbl_branch.branch
FROM vUsers
JOIN tbl_branch ON (SELECT TOP 1 Split.Data.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS BranchID
                     FROM (Select TOP 1 CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(userAccessbranch,',', '</M><M>')+ '</M>'AS XML) AS String
                           FROM vUsers) AS Data
                     CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(Data)) = tbl_branch.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your join expression has this pattern:

```
row set = scalar value
```

where *`row set`* is your `(SELECT Split.Data.value...)` subquery and *`scalar value`*, the `tbl_branch.ID`.

The easiest way to solve this is to flip the sides of the predicate and replace the `=` with either `IN` or `= ANY`. So, it would be either

```
ON tbl_branch.ID IN (SELECT Split.Data.value...)
```

or

```
ON tbl_branch.ID = ANY (SELECT Split.Data.value...)
```

However, arrays are not the strongest side of SQL (or Transact-SQL in particular). The language has been designed to work with row sets rather than arrays. You should really consider changing your schema. A [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) would be a typical approach in such a situation. With it you would have three tables:

- `Users`

  ```
  UserID  UserName
  ------  --------
  1       Putra
  2       Eko
  ...     ...
  ```
- `Branches`

  ```
  BranchID  BranchName
  --------  ----------
  5         New York
  6         Bandung
  7         Jakarta
  ...       ...
  ```
- `UserBranches`

  ```
  UserID  BranchID
  ------  --------
  1       10
  2       5
  1       11
  ...     ...
  ```

And solving your problem would be as trivial as this:

```
SELECT
  u.UserName,
  b.BranchName
FROM
  dbo.Users AS u
  INNER JOIN dbo.UserBranches AS ub ON u.UserID = ub.UserID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Branches AS b ON ub.BranchID = b.BranchID
;
```